# How to make GtkModelButton emit a clicked signal instead of GAction?

Tags: go, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to make a button in GtkPopover like that in Nautilus, and Nautilus uses GtkModelButton for that. The problem is GtkModelButton forces the GAction API, which I think is ugly, and I much prefer using callbacks.

I've tried using GtkButton, but it just looks completely different from GtkModelButton.

My question is, how do I make it so that GtkModelButton works with `mb.Connect("clicked", ...)`? If that doesn't work, what about making GtkButton to look like GtkModelButton? `button.SetRelief(None)` didn't really do the job.

---

ModelButton

[image]

---

ModelButton vs Relief(None) Button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is easier than I thought. All I needed to do was to connect the handler to `button-release-event`!

```golang
btn, _ := gtk.ModelButtonNew()
btn.SetLabel("Click Me!")
btn.Connect("button-release-event", func() bool {
    log.Println("Button pressed.")
    return true
})
```